# $C^{\infty}$ solutions to the functional equation $f(2x)=2\sin(x)f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, fourier-series

What is a rigorous determination of the $C^\infty$ functions $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $f(2x)=2\sin(x)f'(x)$. Several solutions are informally obtained when plugging in the Fourier series.

Comment: sin(x), 1/2-1/2*cos(x)+sin(x), etc. Sorry, I forgot a factor of 2 in the original question, edited it just now.

Comment: Please do not edit your post so much as to make the accepted answer nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that all solutions are linear combinations of $\sin x$ and $1-\cos x$. That they are solutions to the functional differential equation
$$
f(2x)=2f'(x)\sin x \tag{1}
$$
can be checked by direct substitution. On the other hand,
since Eq. $(1)$ is linear, one can try to solve it using Frobenius method. Writing the solution as a power series,
$$
f(x)=x^s\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n, \tag{2}
$$
and replacing $\sin x$ with its power series in $(1)$,
it's easy to show that the lowest order term of the series $(2)$ must satisfy the equation
$$
a_0(2x)^{s}=2sa_0x^s\Rightarrow 2^s = 2s, \tag{3}
$$
which has only two real solutions, $s=1$ and $s=2$. This shows that Eq. $(1)$ has at most two linearly independent solutions that can be represented as a power series. The already mentioned functions  $\sin x$ and $1-\cos x$ fit the bill.